# How to extract string resource for data object in Android?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

object DataService {

```
val categories = listOf(
        Category("JACKET", "jacket_collection"),
        Category("SHIRT", "shirt_collection"),
        Category("PANT", "pant_collection"),
        Category("SHOE", "shoe_collection")
```

)

How can I extract string resource for "JACKET", "SHIRT", "PANT" and "SHOE"?

Answer (score 0):

You can find those value like that::

```
val stringresource = categories.map {it.(your_var_name in Category Class)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    val list = listOf( Category("JACKET", "jacket_collection"),
        Category("SHIRT", "shirt_collection"),
        Category("PANT", "pant_collection"),
        Category("SHOE", "shoe_collection"))
    
    val resource = list.map{it.type} // [JACKET, SHIRT, PANT, SHOE]
```

Your ***Category*** class:

```
data class Category( var type:String, var desc:String)
```